# sys.argv string containing escape sequence characters won't display correctly on LCD

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, sys

I am trying to get some text to display on a 16x2 LCD hooked up to a Raspberry Pi (using Adafruit_CircuitPython_CharLCD library). When the text string is provided within my code, everything works, but when provided as an argument when running the script, I can't get special/escape characters to show correctly.

I have tried to convert `sys.argv[1]` to bytes using `os.fsencode(sys.argv[1])`, then decoding to utf-8 or ascii.
I have searched the library for any specific encoding reference. I don't know much about encoding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#lcd.py

import os, sys
from time import sleep
import board
import digitalio
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd as characterlcd

#LCD setup
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2

lcd_rs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
lcd_en = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)
lcd_d4 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D13)
lcd_d5 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D16)
lcd_d6 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D19)
lcd_d7 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D26)

lcd = characterlcd.Character_LCD_Mono(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)

#Special character definitions
degree = bytes([0xc, 0x12, 0x12, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0])
lcd.create_char(0, degree)


def display(text):
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message = text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    display(" T: 19.5\x00C\nSet 21.0\x00C")
    sleep(5)
    display(sys.argv[1])
```

I call my script as such:
`$ python3 lcd.py " T: 19.5\x00C\nSet 21.0\x00C"`

Right now, it displays correctly for five seconds:

```
 T: 19.5°C
Set 21.0°C
```

And then displays this beauty:

```
 T: 19.5¥x00C¥nS
```

With an empty second line (\n not being recognized).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
" T: 19.5\x00C\nSet 21.0\x00C"
```

*when it is a Python literal* has the `\x00` character sequence interpreted as ASCII 0, which your device is displaying as a degree symbol.

But *when it is data entered on the command line* then `\x00` means the 4 characters `\ x 0 0`. And it is hard to recommend a way around that, because it is tricky to enter the character null from the command line. A lot of intervening software treats that character as a string terminator. So if you must use `\00` as a special character surrogate, let the program continue to manage the formatting (null characters, carriage returns, "Set" and "T:"), while you just feed the numbers in from the command line. Change the `display()` call to

```
display(" T: {1}\x00C\nSet {2}\x00C".format(*sys.argv))
```

and when you run the program, do it like this:

```
$ python3 lcd.py 19.5 21.0
```

This works by passing in the two temperatures as separate values in `sys.argv` which `format()` then puts in the string to be displayed.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input!
Okay that makes sense! I will most likely use your suggested method or something similar because as you guessed, only the temperatures values will end up changing.
It is interesting that there is no easy way to "convert" the characters `\ x 0 0` or even `\ n` to their escape couterparts.